# Does ultrafinitism believe in large, incomprehensible numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

What does the formal doctrine of ulrafinists have to say regarding this?

Comment: Is "incomprehensible" a technical term in set theory?

Answer (score 5):

Here is Harvey Friedman's account of an encounter with the ultra-finitist Yessenin-Volpin:

> I... proceeded to start with 2 and asked him whether this is "real" or something to that effect. He virtually immediately said yes. Then I asked about 4, and he again said yes, but with a perceptible delay. Then 8, and yes, but with more delay. This continued for a couple of more times, till it was obvious how he was handling this objection. Sure, he was prepared to always answer yes, but he was going to take $2^{100}$ times as long to answer yes to $2^{100}$ than he would to answering 2.  There is no  way that I could get very far with this.

Comment: A friend of mine once told me that he got bored as a kid and decided to verify directly the existence of as many natural numbers as he could by counting starting from 1. I think he got to 80,000 or something like that, which is more than I can say for anyone else I know.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  Did he find any that were missing?

Comment: The world record is at least $10^6$: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Harper.

Comment: Actually, this story troubles me, because in the formal systems which are supposed to model ultrafinitistic reasoning, proving the existence of $N$ takes $\sim\log N$ steps, not $\sim N$. So it should have taken $100$ times longer for Yessenin-Volpin to conclude the existence of $2^{100}$ (essentially by using the fact that if multiplication is total: if $m$ and $n$ are meaningful then so is $mn$), not $2^{100}$ times. It is the totality of exponential that is supposed to be problematic, not multiplication. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) So either I don't understand ultrafinitism, or there are several different kinds of ultrafinitism, depending on how much time it takes them to verify the existence of, say $2^{64}$. But considering we do cryptography with numbers much larger than that, it is hard to take the nonexistence of $2^{128}$ seriously!